# Build a list of EC2 instances in each region using python

Tags: python, boto3

I'm trying to loop through all of the regions in each of our AWS accounts and build a list of ec2 instances in each region.

I'm using this loop:

```
import boto3
aws_account = input("Enter the name of the AWS account you'll be working in: ")
session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account)
ec2 = session.client("ec2")
aws_regions = ec2.describe_regions()
for region in aws_regions['Regions']:
    region_name = region['RegionName']
    print("Searching in region: ", region_name)
```

But each time through the loop I always get a list of instances in my default region which is Virginia (us-east-1), repeated over and over again.

What confuses me is that there is no region filter that I can apply to the [describe_instances()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) function of boto3.

How can I loop through the regions and pull a list of instances ONLY from that region?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create client object. It is only associated with single region.

```
ec2 = session.client("ec2")
```

It is documented [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html?highlight=region#boto3.session.Session.region_name) in Boto3,

> region_name (string) -- The name of the region associated with the
>   client. A client is associated **with a single region.**

That is why your loop will print only us-east-1 (default) associated with that account.

Also, since all the time it is going to associate with one region, there is no point in providing filter for describe-instances.

To solve your issue, I believe you should be looping in sessions and clients (one for each region)